# For-each loop not iterating over an array that is read from local storage

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage

Getting an error message saying that "taskOutput is not iterable". The array looks like this:

```
const taskOutput = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("taskList")) || [];
```

The loop looks like this:

```
 for (const task of taskOutput) {
        const taskEl = document.createElement("div");
        const {participant, duetime, description} = task;

        // PROGRESSION-BAR
        let newDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
        let newBtn = document.createElement("button");
        let btnText = document.createTextNode("Fullfør");
        newBtn.appendChild(btnText);

        newDiv.style.border = "3px solid black";
        newDiv.style.height = "10px";
        newDiv.style.backgroundColor = task.color; 

        newBtn.onclick = function() {
            if(task.color === "red"){
                task.color = "green"; 
                localStorage.setItem('taskList', JSON.stringify(taskOutput)); 

            }
            else if(task.color === "green"){
                task.color = "red"; 
                localStorage.setItem('taskList', JSON.stringify(taskOutput)); 
                newDiv.style.backgroundColor = task.color; 
            }
        }
```

Comment: this is more than 150 lines of code to read! what you are asking is to pass 1 hour to read and understand what you do, and 1 more hour to make an answer... you have to make a synthetic, Minimal, Reproducible Example of what you are looking for to expect have answer, and follow SO recommendations stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you for providing me with the right convention to post a question Mister Jojo. I'll edit it

Comment: Can you show what value you get on execugting this line `console.log(taskOutput)`

Comment: {category: "work", participant: "dasfs", duetime: "0005-12-31", description: "adsfsg", color: "red"}
I am getting the object passed to local storage

Comment: `const taskList = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("taskList")) `
`const taskOutput = taskList ? [taskList] :  [];`

Comment: That's not an array :/ Your local storage apparently contains one task, not an array of tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The for...of statement creates a loop iterating over iterable objects, including: built-in String, Array, array-like objects.

Your taskOuput is an object when retrieved from localStorage after parsing; which is not iterable using `for of` loop

Try updating the code to this,

```
const taskList = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("taskList")) 
const taskOutput = taskList ? [taskList] : [];
```

Comment: Great, happy to help :)

Comment: @LaurentBaj Request you to accept the ans since it worked for you